# Find longest ordered sequence in unordered list

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to find the longest sequence in an unordered list and return their indices. Is there room for improvement? How can I find out the worst-case runtime of this? I'm quite new to algorithms and run times. Thanks!

```
def find_longest_array(array):
    start = 0
    end = 0
    for left in range(len(array)):
        for right in range(left + 1, len(array)):
            sub_array = array[left:right+1]
            if sorted(sub_array) == sub_array:
                if len(sub_array) > end - start:
                    start, end = left, right
                if end == len(array):
                    return start, end
            else:
                break
    return start, end
```

Comment: For a (full) review of working code, check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: For feedback on working code, check out our sister site [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: I feel like it would be a lot faster to step through the list and see if the current element is not less than the previous one while keeping track of a counter and the longest sequence so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program runs in O(n^3 log n) time which is quite inefficient.

How do we arrive at the O(n^3 log n) figure?

1. You consider each subarray once: there are n^2 subarrays.
2. Then, you sort each array and compare it to itself: nlogn for each array.

---

There is a linear-time approach to this.

Let `dp[i]` indicate the longest ordered sequence ending at position `i`.

Then:

`dp[i]` can be formed by

- either continuing the previous sequence ending at `i - 1` (only possible if `arr[i] >= arr[i - 1]` so as to maintain the ordering)
- or by starting a new ordered sequence at this point.

Thus, compute `dp[i] = (dp[i - 1] + 1) if arr[i] >= arr[i - 1] or 1`  for all `i` ≠ 0.

Finally, return the largest value amongst all `dp[i]`.

If you want to return the actual left and right bounds for the largest array, you iterate backwards from `i` where `i` is the largest `dp[i]`.

---

In fact, you can do away with `dp` entirely, and merely keep track of the *length of the current sequence* and the *length and position of the largest sequence seen so far*.

But I feel that this approach is easier to grok and easier to write correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I still want to answer this, and I don't have enough rep to comment. Is this allowed?

Yes, there's room for improvement, you're iterating on the inside loop longer than necessary, and sorting the entire inner list repeatedly.

Improvements:
First, you only need to compare two values at a time (this and the next). Second, once you find something that doesn't line up, you can break out of the nested loop. 
Last point is just for calling fewer functions: I personally like using python's enumerate instead of range(len):

```py
list = [1, 5, 78, 2, 3, 6, 8, 1, 7, 2, 9, 3, 7, 2]

print(list)
length = 0 
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    a = item
    for index2,following in enumerate(list[index:]):
        b = following
        if sorted([a,b]) != [a,b]: #comparison here, looking for break in pattern
            if index2>length:
                length = index2
                start = index
            break
        a = b #update current value to continue

print ("Sequence {} long, between {} and {}".format(length, start, start+length-1))
print(list[start:start+length])
```

output:

```
[1, 5, 78, 2, 3, 6, 8, 1, 7, 2, 9, 3, 7, 2]
Sequence 4 long, between 3 and 6
[2, 3, 6, 8]
```

But I'm sure there's a while loop solution in there ;)

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient approach to solve this in linear time (of *O(n)* time complexity) is to keep track of the starting index of the current ordered sequence, as well as the starting and ending indices of the longest sequence, and update the starting and ending indices of the longest sequence if the length of the current ordered sequence is greater than the previous longest sequence. Reset the starting index to the current index if an out-of-order item is encountered:

```
def find_longest_array(array):
    longest_start = longest_end = start = 0
    for i, n in enumerate(array):
        if i:
            if array[i - 1] > n:
                start = i
            elif i - start > longest_end - longest_start:
                longest_start, longest_end = start, i
    return longest_start, longest_end
```

so that:

```
find_longest_array((2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5))
```

returns:

```
(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in O(n) time without for loops using zip and list comprehensions:

```
L = [1, 5, 78, 2, 3, 6, 8, 1, 7, 2, 9, 3, 7, 2]

breaks = [0] + [ i+1 for (i,n),p in zip(enumerate(L),L[1:]) if n>p ] + [len(L)]
size,start,end = max([ (e-s,s,e) for s,e in zip(breaks,breaks[1:]) ])
```

- `breaks` identifies indexes for the beginning of increasing sequences

  [0, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14]
- `zip(breaks,breaks[1:])` then pairs these into consecutive ranges

  [(0, 3), (3, 7), (7, 9), (9, 11), (11, 13), (13, 14)]
- getting the maximum (by length) yields the answer directly.

  `print(size, start, end, L[start:end]) # 4 3 7 [2, 3, 6, 8]`